# prove that $\vert f (x) \vert$ attains every value in the open interval $(0, \epsilon)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

hey I need help with the question below :

> Let $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Suppose that $f$ is not a
>   constant function and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x) = 0$.
>
> Then there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $| f (x) |$ attains every value in the open interval $(0, \varepsilon)$.

thank you .

Comment: Use the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It would be helpful if you could please update your question with your own effort on the problem -- what you tried and where you got stuck. We will be happy to guide you from there.

Comment: im having hard time to start the question can i get any lead ?

Comment: can someone help

Comment: Hint: "Suppose that $f$ is not a constant function": try to express that formally.

Answer (score 0):

Put $|f|=:g$. Since $f$ is not a constant function there is an $\epsilon>0$ and a $\>b\in{\mathbb R}$ such that $g(b)=|f(b)|=\epsilon$. Let an arbitrary $\eta\in(0,\epsilon)$ be given. As $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=0$ there is a $c>b$ such that $g(c)\leq {\eta\over2}$. From the intermediate value theorem it then follows that there is a $\xi\in(b,c)$ with $g(\xi)=\eta$.

Answer (score 0):

Try to visualize what they are asking and put it in terms of $f$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to\pm \infty} f(x) = 0$.

They are asking you to prove there is an $\epsilon$ so that for any $w \in (0, \epsilon)$ there is an $x$ so that $|f(x)| = w$.

Now the most useful theorem we have at our disposal is the intermediate value theorem.  If we can prove there is an $a$ so that i) $|f(a)| > w$ and that ii) there is an $b$ so that $|f(b)| < w$ then by IVT there is a $c$ between $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $f(c) =w$.

To show i) depends on the value of $w$.  If $|f(x)|$ has a maximum value for instance and $w$ is greater than that max, this is impossible.  But $0 < w < \epsilon$ and $\epsilon$ is entirely within our choice.  If we have *any* $x'$ where $|f(x')| > 0$ we can just say, let $\epsilon: 0 < \epsilon < |f(x') |$ then for any $w: 0 < w < \epsilon < |f(x')|$ we'd be done.  Just let $a = x'$ and we have $|f(a)| > w$.

So we just have to show there exist an $a$ so that $|f(a)| > 0$.  BUt $f$ is not constant.  So it is not true that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$.  so there is *some* $x'$ where $f(x')\ne 0$ so $|f(x')| > 0$.  So let $a = x'$ and $\epsilon = f(a)$ so we have $0 < w < \epsilon = |f(a)| = |f(x')|$.

To show ii) we use the definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.  That means, *by definition*, that for any $w > 0$ there is an $N$ so that for all $x > M$ we have $|f(x)| < w$.  And that's it.  Pick any real number $b$ where $b > a$ and $b > N$ and we have $|f(b)| <w$.

So we have $0 < |f(b)| < w < |f(a)|$ and as $|f(x)|$ is continuous by IVT there is a $c$ so that $f(c) = w$ for every $x \in (0,\epsilon= |f(a)|)$.

We are done.

.....

Okay...I know what I hear people saying.  Didn't we assume the value of $\epsilon$ before we knew the value of $a$, which we then used $a$ to define $\epsilon$?  Isn't that circular?

Well, no.  My point in the above was to show a student how to think about solving the problem.    Often thinking about a problem involves thinking of the end and working backwards.  And thus can seem circular.  If we consider that a rough draft the final draft would be as follows:

As $f$ is not constant there exists an $x'$ where $f(x') \ne 0$.  Let $\epsilon = |f(x')|> 0$.

For any $w\in (0, \epsilon)$ we know $w < \epsilon = |f(x')|$.

$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$ so that means that as $w>0$ there is an $N$ so that if $x > N$ then $|f(x)| < w$.

So for any $x'' > \max(N,x')$ we have $|f(x')| > w > |f(x'')|$.

As $f$ is continuous, $|f|$ is also continuous.  So by IVT there is a $c: x'< c < x''$ so that $|f(c)| = w$.

And that had no circularity.  (But we had to know where we were going from the beginining.)